# Dual booted by accident?

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot

I have been using different linux distribution via virtual box for the past month. Last weekend found an old laptop with a dead hard drive and changed it out for a totally new hard drive, with nothing on it. I usb booted linux mint on to the old laptop, but when I got to the install it kept failing at Grub throwing back an error ".. 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader...."

I tried to use all the online solutions I could but I noticed when I got to the installer screen giving options on how I wanted to install i.e "write over hard drive" "try something else" it provided the option of installing linux mint alongside linux mint. Which made no sense as I couldn't access an actual linux mint that was written to the hard drive (just the live boot, which wouldn't save anything when I shut down). I eventually thought chose the option to install linux mint alongside linux mint, out of frustration. Install worked and when I restarted the machine it gave me Grub with two linux mint options which were both fully installed... Is there a way to change one of my dual boots to something else ? another OS?

TLDR dual booted the same OS (linux mint) by accident. Is there a way to change one of my dual boots to something else ? another OS?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a "recent" laptop that uses **UEFI** and has the `Secure Boot` feature enabled, this mechanism enforced by Microsoft to it's vendors requires boot loaders to be digitally signed by a trusted authority in order to run. Most current linux distros have unsigned boot loaders, hence the problem.

If you are ***not*** interesed in installing Windows on this machine, you can disable the secure boot feature in the **EFI** settings.

If you need to have Windows installed alongside other OS on this machine, you will have to hunt for a signed boot loader probably something efilinux based.

Comment: Actually, you can install windows with secure boot disabled. I have such a Linux/Windows dual-boot setup on my Desktop PC. This is at least the case for Windows 8 - Windows 10 may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should be able to simply format over the partition that the second Mint system is installed on and then run `sudo update-grub`. You can then install a different OS on that free partition.

I would also check your EFI System Partition to make sure there is only 1 version of GRUB installed (if not, remove the redundant one).